# Psql, pgAdmin don't show inserted tables, despite the fact that project is working, I'm confused

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, psql, typeorm

I'm making a blog website on a stack - `typescript` with `typeorm` sitting on the `node` /w `express`. I've successfully implemented authorization, I'm able to register user, then log in with proper cred., but to my suprise - my database seems to be empty (in `pgAdmin`, and also in `psql` using `SELECT * FROM user;`)

I'm sure that's some silly mistake or my misunderstanding, yet - I just don't understand why it happens, I'm confused.

`ormconfig.json`

```
  {
    "name": "development",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "secret",
    "database": "bloo_dev", <-- my database
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
    "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
```

`ormConnect.ts`

```
import { User } from "../entity/User.entity";
import { Article } from "../entity/Article.entity";

export const ormConnect = async () => {
  const options = await getConnectionOptions(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  return process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? createConnection({
        ...options,
        url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        entities: [User, Article],
        name: "default",
      } as any)
    : createConnection({ <-- this one gets called
        ...options,
        //url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        entities: [User, Article],
        name: "default",
      } as any);
};
```

And everything seems to work completely fine from the app perspective, I'm sure that I've added new user, becouse I can log in with his cred. later.

Comment: you are looking in the wrong database....

Comment: maybe you need to run the migrations to add data?

Comment: @Luuk I'm not, I've checked it a couple of times.

Comment: @WilsonPena Isn't synchronize supposed to make it work without migrations?

Comment: But, you are "able to register user, then log in with proper cred", and "my database seems to be empty", then, my guess which applies in 99 out of 100 times, is you are looking in the wrong database... 

Comment: synchronize will put the changes in the entities to the database. but there is a command you need to run to run the migrations: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md

Comment: I mean, all of the tables were created. They are just empty.

Comment: so do these migrations add data to the tables?

Comment: are there inserts in the migrations files?

Comment: I will make a migration and then check if everything works fine then.